# what is the equation for Thomas-Fermi screening length for 2D material at 1D interface?

Tags: solid-state-physics

I have a 1D interface of two different 2D materials (in-plane heterostructure)

is it still the same as:

$$ r_{TF} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{a_0^3}{n} \right) ^{1/6} $$